# How to ignore uncommitted messages from a Kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to have a Kakfa consumer that is able to fulfill two requisits:

1. Consume all messages when asked for it (got it)
2. Discard/ignore all messages that have not been committed (need help)

To keep things simple, I'll only have one topic and one partition running.
This is how I set up my consumer:

```
private Consumer<Long, String> createConsumer() {
    final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "KafkaExampleConsumer");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());

    final Consumer<Long, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);

    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));
    return consumer;
}
```

And this is the method I use to fulfill requisit number 1:

```
public void write() {
    final ConsumerRecords<Long, String> consumerRecords = transactionsConsumer.poll(1000);
    consumerRecords.forEach(record -> System.out.printf("Consumer Record:(%d, %s, %d, %d)\n",
                record.key(), record.value(), record.partition(), record.offset()));

    transactionsConsumer.commitAsync(); 
}
```

It works fine, but, as for requisit number 2 I don't really get what is the best way to proceed. I know I can just implement a `write()` look-a-like method that consumes and does not print anything, but that seems too much work for just ignoring messages. Plus, if I have lots of messages to be consumed, it could be expensive to do so, I think. I took a look to methods such as `seekToEnd(partition)`, but couldn't get it to work properly.

Comment: All messages being consumed are ***acknowledged*** by the leader broker... Consumers are responsible for committing, not reading "committed messages", so I'm not sure I understand the question. Maybe you can explain what you're really trying to do? If you want to seek to offsets, then explain what error you get when trying

Comment: It is not a requisit that the messages must be committed. I just want to discard/ignore all unread messages when I invoke this new method I want to implement. The error I get when invoking `seekToEnd()` is "no current assignment for partition test-0".

Comment: So every time you start a consumer, you always want to start at the end? I'm not entirely sure kafka is the best technology for that use case, but can you update your question to include that seeking code?

Answer (score 0):

For read committed messages, you must set

> **isolation.level=read_committed**

in your consumer's configuration.

> In read_committed mode, the consumer will read only those transactional messages which have been successfully committed. It will continue to read non-transactional messages as before. There is no client-side buffering in read_committed mode. Instead, the end offset of a partition for a read_committed consumer would be the offset of the first message in the partition belonging to an open transaction. This offset is known as the 'Last Stable Offset'(LSO).